# Is it possible to generate columns based on input columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, calendar, conditional-statements, series

I have a table like this in PostgreSQL with 3 initial columns called **Project**, **Size**, and **StartDate** (see below):

| Project | Size | StartDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Project1 | 88 | 2020-06-15 |
| Project2 | 105 | 2020-03-01 |

I need to add ***12 columns*** next to **StartDate** column and extend the initial table to **15 columns**. All new columns represent months for given year (2020), and they will contain 0 and values calculated based on conditional logic derived from **Size** and **StartDate** columns. The condition is the following: *if the **StartDate** belongs to a specific month, that month gets a value=Size* and after that for each next month the Value=Value-50 until Value >0. Please check the expected outcome below:

| Project | Size | StartDate | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | Mai | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Project1 | 88 | 2020-06-15 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 88 | 38 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Project2 | 105 | 2020-03-01 | 0 | 0 | 105 | 55 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a lot of `CASE` expressions:

```
SELECT project,
       size,
       startdate,
       CASE WHEN mon < 2
            THEN greatest(size - 50 * (1 - mon), 0)
            ELSE 0
       END AS jan,
       CASE WHEN mon < 3
            THEN greatest(size - 50 * (2 - mon), 0)
            ELSE 0
       END AS feb,
       CASE WHEN mon < 4
            THEN greatest(size - 50 * (3 - mon), 0)
            ELSE 0
       END AS mar,
       CASE WHEN mon < 5
            THEN greatest(size - 50 * (4 - mon), 0)
            ELSE 0
       END AS apr,
       CASE WHEN mon < 6
            THEN greatest(size - 50 * (5 - mon), 0)
            ELSE 0
       END AS may,
       CASE WHEN mon < 7
            THEN greatest(size - 50 * (6 - mon), 0)
            ELSE 0
       END AS jun,
       CASE WHEN mon < 8
            THEN greatest(size - 50 * (7 - mon), 0)
            ELSE 0
       END AS jul,
       CASE WHEN mon < 9
            THEN greatest(size - 50 * (8 - mon), 0)
            ELSE 0
       END AS aug,
       CASE WHEN mon < 10
            THEN greatest(size - 50 * (9 - mon), 0)
            ELSE 0
       END AS sep,
       CASE WHEN mon < 11
            THEN greatest(size - 50 * (10 - mon), 0)
            ELSE 0
       END AS oct,
       CASE WHEN mon < 12
            THEN greatest(size - 50 * (11 - mon), 0)
            ELSE 0
       END AS nov,
       CASE WHEN mon < 13
            THEN greatest(size - 50 * (12 - mon), 0)
            ELSE 0
       END AS dec
FROM (SELECT project,
             size,
             startdate,
             extract(month FROM startdate) AS mon
      FROM mytable) AS q;
```

Comment: thank you so very much for this great idea. It works perfectly. Will be very grateful if you could consider and help with a modification of this problem.  Is it possible to have the initial value twice in a row and then do the subtraction. In case of Project1 the row  will look like this:  0,0,0,0, 88, 88,38, 0,0,0,0,0